# IntersectionObserver

Tags: javascript

Как можно отловить появление выдвигающейся панели при помощи IntersectionObserver?

```
function test() {
const elm = document.querySelector('.panel');
const options = {
    root: null,
    rootMargin: '0px',
    threshold: 0}

observer = new IntersectionObserver(elements => {
elements.forEach(element => {
if(element.intersectionRatio > 0) {
    var intersectionRatio = element.intersectionRatio;
    var isIntersecting = element.isIntersecting;
    var time = element.time;}
    });
});
observer.observe(elm );
return time;}
```

Но когда панель еще не открыта, то выходит такая ошибка:

```
VM32254:16 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'observe' on 'IntersectionObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.
at test (<anonymous>:16:14)
at <anonymous>:1:1
```

По умолчанию такого элемента нет (с таким классом), он появляется только при нажатии на элемент таблицы

Comment: а что если засунуть этот код в обработчик кнопки? если только там создается элемент

Comment: вы сказали, что панель создается при клике. В этот момент добавьте созданную панель в обсервер, все. Вам не нужен будет класс, потому что у вас есть созданный элемент сам

Comment: `observer.observe(elm );` вам вот эта строчка нужна, все остальное можно где угодно определять, главное что бы потом можно было ссылку на `observer` получить